# How do I replace all the 0 values in a range with a formula depending on the category it's in?

Tags: excel, vba

On an excel sheet, if there is a list of numbers and next to it a letter to determine what category it's in, how would I be able to change blank or 0 values with a formula depending on the category?

In this case there's a list of price and weight for product a,b,and c. the average price for the products are already known and is in a table on the same excel sheet. To fill in the 0 data with an estimate of how much the product would've weighed, what would the code look like.

[image: An example]

```
Sub test()

Dim RNG As Range

 
For Each RNG In Range("A2:A")

    If RNG.Value = "0" And RNG.Offset(0, 2) = "a" Then RNG.Offset(0, 0).Formula = "=RC[1]/Cells(2,5)"

    If RNG.Value = "0" And RNG.Offset(0, 2) = "b" Then RNG.Offset(0, 0).Formula = "=RC[1]/Cells(3,5)"

    If RNG.Value = "0" And RNG.Offset(0, 2) = "c" Then RNG.Offset(0, 0).Formula = "=RC[1]/Cells(4,5)"
    Next RNG
 
End Sub
```

The real data is thousands of lines so manually doing it is not prefered. There are a few things like the RNG.Offest(0,0) that I'm not particularly happy about but it doesn't return a syntax error so i've stuck with it.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Seems to me `RNG.Offset(0,0).Formula` is the same as `RNG,Formula`. If you set the formula to be `"=RC[1]/Cells(2,5)"` then that is exactly what it will be. Cocnsider using `RNG.Offset(0,-1).Address & "/E2"` instead

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken to understand what you want ...

The code below assumed that all the data rows in column D are unique.

```
Sub test1()
Dim rg As Range
Dim cell As Range

With ActiveSheet
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In rg
        If cell.Value = 0 Then _
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value / .Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
End With

End Sub

Sub test2()
Dim rg As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim c As String

With ActiveSheet
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In rg
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            c = .Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Address
            cell.Value = "=" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "/" & c & ""
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Sub test1 will put a value to the cell which value = 0
Sub test2 will put a formula to the cell which value = 0

(based on your image attachment) :
cell A4 show a result from a calculation of : cell B4 value / cell E2 value = 1.0333
cell A7 show a result from a calculation of : cell B7 value / cell E3 value = 3.3293

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologise for the confusingly random example data. This has been very helpful